Run electron application from dockerfile
I've written a simple electron application that displays and modifies an embedded sqlite database and starts some external processes.
It works fine on my linux VM.
Now I want to containerize that application with the following dockerfile:
FROM node:20
# install electron dependencies or more if your library has other dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install xorg xvfb gtk2-engines-pixbuf \
dbus-x11 xfonts-base xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-scalable \
libx11-xcb1 libxcb-dri3-0 libxtst6 libnss3 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libxss1 \
libasound2 libdrm2 libgbm1 libglvnd-dev dbus nano xauth  \
-yq --no-install-suggests --no-install-recommends   \
&& apt-get clean \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
ENV DISPLAY=:0
# copy the source into /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN chown -R node /app
RUN pwd
RUN ls -l
USER node
RUN npm install 
## change dir to install application
WORKDIR bot-app
RUN pwd 
RUN npm install 
RUN npx electron-rebuild
RUN ls -l
# Electron needs root for sandboxing
USER root
RUN chown root /app/bot-app/node_modules/electron/dist/chrome-sandbox
RUN chmod 4755 /app/bot-app/node_modules/electron/dist/chrome-sandbox
##EXPOSE 8085
# Electron doesn't like to run as root
USER node
##CMD ["npm", "start"]
CMD ["bash"]

I want to run that image with the command below:
sudo docker run -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -e DISPLAY=<my server id> -it matrix-bot-app bash

with the result shown below:
node@abc:/app/bot-app$ npm start

> bot-app@1.0.0 start
> electron . --no-sandbox

[28:1022/092728.947577:ERROR:bus.cc(407)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[28:1022/092729.085827:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(245)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY
[28:1022/092729.085847:ERROR:env.cc(258)] The platform failed to initialize.  Exiting.
FATAL ERROR: Error::ThrowAsJavaScriptException napi_throw
----- Native stack trace -----

/app/bot-app/node_modules/electron/dist/electron exited with signal SIGABRT


Any idea? Many many thanks !

Can you run GUI applications in a Linux Docker container? has extensive discussion on setting up an X application; is an answer to your problem there?  Note that this setup is complicated and Linux-specific, and you will probably find it substantially easier to run this program without involving Docker.
